# Is it a bad idea to have many protected variables, events and procedures in a unit?

Tags: object-oriented, delphi

I am writing a full fledged p2p networking library on top of Indy's UDP server with an intention of publishing it online. The design I have implemented has a P2P manager ( TIdUDPServer ) which can act as a server or a peer. Each connected peer is represented by a separate object which contains additional features and information about them. The classes are both contained in a single unit.

For the purpose of simplification, I have declared those members used by either, under protected. Somehow, my instincts are giving me a bad feeling about this. The P2P manager has very few members but the peer object has nearly everything under protected. Going the other way will most certainly introduce a whole lot of code and method calls.

I need to know;

1. Is it a good practice for networking libraries to have protected members?
2. Should I replace the variables with properties under protected? With getters and setters or direct access would be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see what the type of library should have to do with the architecture of your code in general.

As a general rule of thumb, it is better to start with high restrictions, you can lower them all the time. Encapsulation is a valuable good, it can help a great deal to keep things decoupled. It's much harder going the other way, moving something from `published` down the road to `private`. For example, for interfaced classes (especially refcounted ones), I would recommend to put all `interface` methods under `protected` to enforce this way for such classes and just leave the CTOR/DTORs `public`.

Regarding getters/setters: If in doubt, make it a `property`. Delphi is smart enough to replace acesses to simple properties like

```
property foo : string read ffoo write ffoo;
```

with direct variable access, just check the generated CPU code.

Aside from that, I would prefer `strict protected/private` rather than just `protected/private` wherever possible.